# Does the discriminant of a polynomial depend on the underlying field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, galois-theory

Say I want to show the discriminant of $X^4 + rX + s \in \mathbb{Q}[X]$ is $-27r^4 + 256s^3$. I can do this by showing it's a symmetric polynomial in r,s so by total degree in the roots it's a linear combination of $r^4,  s^3$, and plugging in e.g. $-1,0$ then $0,-1$ as values of $r,s$ to determine the constants.

I realise this works in over any base field with characteristic not equal to 3 in exactly the same way (taking the numbers to mean their image under the ring hom from $\mathbb{Z}$ where $1 \mapsto 1$). However some care is needed for characteristic 3 in the $-1,0$ case because there are no primitive 3rd roots of 1.

I realise that the roots are just 0,1 and so one can easily show it holds in char 3 too. Possibly if you are careful you can show that the manipulations that involved a primitive 3rd root didn't actually use primitivity, but is there a more fundamental reason why the discriminant of a polynomial shouldn't depend on the base field?

Comment: What definition are you using for discriminant?  If you use the definition in terms of the determinant of the Sylvester matrix of the polynomial and its derivative, that's an explicit polynomial with integer coefficients, and no mention of the base field.

Comment: @RobertIsrael The only definition I am familiar with is a product of differences of pairs of roots squared